# Jasmine test cases issues

Tags: jasmine

I am writing Jasmine to check the my UI script.

I have written couple of test cases to check my UI script. One of the test case is throwing exception because of some issue, because of this exception all my test cases are failing.

It is a becoming difficult to find the failure test case.

How can I identify the failure test cases?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you gave us more information.  Why not cut and paste the error messages and the test code?

Answer (score 1):

You can run only specific `describe` by changing it to `ddescribe`. You can do the same with it statement by changing `it` to `iit`. Experiment with this to help you identify the test in problem.